# Empty space right of the text if only max-width set

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with basics of css. I want to show message in chat like WhatsApp or other chat apps. If text is shorter than max-width of the container, it works fine. But if this text is longer than max-width, than text is wrapped on new lines and takes max-width of the container, even if every its string is shorter. It looks like empty space right of the text.

What is the best way to show messages in my case? Is it possible without scripts?

```css
.container {
  max-width: 400px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      test_test_test_test_test_test_test_test test_test_test_test_test_test_test_test 
      test_test_test_test_test_test_test_test test_test_test_test_test_test_test_test
</div>
```

Comment: I want the text content to occupy the width it really needs. How to do it, unfortunately I do not know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not clear on what the behaviour you are expecting is.  When there are long words, the text must wrap over multiple lines if the container cannot grow.

However, there is a CSS property named [`word-break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) that allows you to dictate how the words behave when breaking over to the next line.

In this case, using `word-break: break-all` will specify that the text can fill the remaining space and break mid-word onto the next line.  This is shown in the snippet below:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 400px;
  background: green;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      one_one_one_one_one_one_one_one_one_one two_two_two_two_two_two_two_two_two_two 
      three_three_three_three_three_three_thr four_four_four_four_four_four_four_four
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have so long *words*, there is one ugly hack, set `display: table-caption`. I don't see better solution...

Maybe, you should work with real texts and not with 300px long words.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 400px;
  display: table-caption;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      test_test_test_test_test_test_test_test test_test_test_test_test_test_test_test 
      test_test_test_test_test_test_test_test test_test_test_test_test_test_test_test
</div>
```

Comment: Long words it's the worst case. Of course real content of the chat has usually other words. Thank you, I'll read about this "table-caption".

Comment: It works but it's really ugly hack (`display: table-caption` isn't for this type of task), I can't say it's a 'solution'. Maybe you should consider `word-wrap` and work will full 400px width.

Comment: Okay, I understood that only one way to do is to handle text with a script. I noticed that Viber show long words with empty spaces too, although I was sure that they solved this problem. Thank you for our answer!

Comment: @V.Perfilev There are more options: this one hack, word-wrap, putting space after Xth char, putting triple dot between Xth and Yth char (typically long URLs, https://example.com/dir...contact.php), divide long words and the end of line - https://mnater.github.io/Hyphenator/, etc. Depends on your use case.